# How to stack push notifications in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

I am dealing with push notifications. When I get multiple notifications, they all show up in the status bar. I need a solution where only one icon is displayed in the status bar and the notifications are stacked one above the other.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Group of Notifications: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/group

> Starting in Android 7.0 (API level 24), you can choose to display related notifications in a group (previously called "bundled" notifications). For example, if your app shows notifications for received emails, you should put all notifications into the same group so they can be collapsed together.

Comment: i went through the setgroup() method. but for every new notification, a icon is seen in the status bar . My requirement is i should get the notifications  stacked one above the other , but only one notification icon should be displayed.i used the "inbox style" but there adding of lines is static . how do i display multiple notifications with different notifications id , but from the same application , stacked one above the other . very much like watsapp . The previous notifications shouldnt be replaced by the incoming new notification, rather i want it to be stacked.

Comment: @freddy pradeep Is your problem similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521908/android-gcm-multiple-push-notifications-with-one-icon-in-status-bar